# Django Ajax post 500 internal error

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

i hope you can help me, im trying to make a django post form without reloading the page using ajax, but im getting error 500 when submit, can you help me to fix this, this is my code:

models.py

```
class ProductoConcepto(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    orden = models.ForeignKey(Cobro)
    cantidad = models.FloatField()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cobro import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cobro/agregar_concepto/$', views.addconcept_product, name='add_concepto'),
]
```

views.py

```
def addconcept_product(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            producto = request.POST['producto']
            orden = request.POST['orden']
            cantidad = request.POST['cantidad']

            ProductoConcepto.objects.create(producto=producto, orden=orden, cantidad=cantidad)

            return HttpResponse('')
```

template

```
    <div class="modal inmodal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-m">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span>
                        </button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Agregar nuevo concepto</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Datos de concepto a agregar:</p>
                        <div class="doctorformstyle">
                        <form id='formulario-modal' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <ul>{{form2.as_p}}</ul>

<!--  rendered form2 fields: <select id="id_producto" name="producto"><option value="1" selected="selected">object</option></select> -->
<!--  form2 fields: <select id="id_orden" name="orden">
<option value="1" selected="selected">object</option>
</select> -->
<!--  form2 fields: <input id="id_cantidad" name="cantidad" step="any" type="number"> -->

                            <div class="row align-center">
                                <input type='submit' name="save1" value='Guardar' class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary"/>
                            </div>

                        </form>
</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#formulario-modal', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url 'add_concepto' %}',
                data: {
                    producto: $('#id_producto').val(),
                    orden: $('#id_orden').val(),
                    cantidad: $('#id_cantidad').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },
                sucess:function(){
                    alert("OK");
                }
            })
    });

</script>
```

this is the error:  POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/cobro/agregar_concepto/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

I think that maybe something is missing in my view, buy i dont know that, cal you help me?

Edit: Traceback added

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/cobro/agregar_concepto/
>
> Django Version: 1.9.7 Python Version: 2.7.11 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'entrada', 
>   'cobro',  'catalogo',  'selectize',  'smart_selects') Installed
>   Middleware: ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   get_response
>     158.                                  % (callback.**module**, view_name))
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /cobro/agregar_concepto/ Exception
>   Value: The view cobro.views.addconcept_product didn't return an
>   HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Please show the full error traceback. I think some exception is getting raised.

Comment: sure, i edited the post.

Comment: So its clear from the error that you are returning None from the view, and that's why you are getting the exception and a 500 status.Atleast return something like return HttpResponse('Product Created !')

Comment: can you explain me how to fix that, i'm still learning this and sometimes i can't see the errors so clearly, also thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You view is not complete:
As the exception states: The view cobro.views.addconcept_product didn't return an proper HttpResponse object.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Comment: ooh i see, but in this case i'm using ajax to avoid redirect or reload the page, so still needs the response object? or for that is something missing in my script to make the post

Comment: You have to return a valid HttpResponse or a JsonResponse

Answer (score 0):

Update your return statement with something like.

```
return HttpResponse('Product Created !')
```

Also as you are using ajax, you can also return a JsonResponse.

First import it

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

and then return your response

```
JsonResponse({'success': 'Product created'})
```

The exception is getting raised because you are not handling the condition if the method is not POST, and you are submitting a GET request.

Handle the cases for invalid form and if method is not POST.

```
def addconcept_product(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():
     ....

        return JsonResponse({'success': 'Product created'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'InValid Form.Product Creation Failed'})
else:
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Only POST method allowed'})
```

Also use ajax method attribute instead of type.

```
$.ajax ({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '{% url 'add_concepto' %}',
    ....
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i tried that but i get the same exception.

Comment: Also change your ajax `type: 'POST',` attribute with `method: 'POST',` and handle the condition if your method is not post, like adding `else:  JsonResponse({'error': 'Only post allowed'})`

Comment: yes, but i'm stil getting the 500 error, that why i posted all my code lol, i thought tha maybe i was wrong with something else.

Comment: i'm based on this tutorial to make it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI&index=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you viewing the exception you provided in a new window? Because it is showing 
"Request Method: GET" which shouldn't be happening via your ajax function.

Modify your view to this:

```
def addconcept_product(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            producto = request.POST['producto']
            orden = request.POST['orden']
            cantidad = request.POST['cantidad']

            ProductoConcepto.objects.create(producto=producto, orden=orden, cantidad=cantidad)

            return HttpResponse('Product Created')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Product Creation failed')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Failed: Post requests only.')
```